# Row_number() and partition by statement of sql is not working in java class

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a sql query which is working fine in sql server 2012 but not working in java class .It gives error **Incorrect syntax near 'INDUS2_VACUUM'.** some error is always shown near **`rn"+`**.Whatever changes I do error is shown near rn. Can't we execute such query in java class and obtain the ResultSet?

Sql query in my java class is

```js
WITH cte AS (SELECT b.logtime,b.beam_current,b.beam_energy,"+
                        "case when a.st2_vs2_bag1_onoff=0 then c.st2_vs2_bag1_rb ELSE 0 END as st2_vs2_bag1_rb,"+
          "CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag2_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag2_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag2_rb,"+
            "CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag3_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag3_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag3_rb,"+
           "CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag4_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag4_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag4_rb,"+
             "CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag5_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag5_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag5_rb,"+
           "CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag6_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag6_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag6_rb,"+
            "CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag7_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag7_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag7_rb,"+
          "CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag8_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag8_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag8_rb,"+
           "CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag9_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag9_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag9_rb ,"+
       "Row_number() OVER(partition BY b.beam_current ORDER BY b.logtime) rn"+
 "FROM INDUS2_VACUUM.dbo.main_vacuum_analog c INNER JOIN INDUS2_VACUUM.dbo.main_vacuum_status a"+
                       "ON c.logtime = a.logtime INNER JOIN INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT b ON a.LOGTIME = b.LOGTIME"+
      "WHERE  b.logtime BETWEEN '2014-08-09 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-09 23:59:59'"+
                      "AND b.beam_current in('10.01', '20.02', '39.97', '40.04', '50.05', '60.0', '69.96', '79.97', '90.03', '109.96', '119.97', '129.98')AND b.beam_energy BETWEEN '550' AND '551')"+
                   "Select logtime,beam_current,beam_energy,st2_vs2_bag1_rb,st2_vs2_bag2_rb,st2_vs2_bag3_rb,st2_vs2_bag4_rb,st2_vs2_bag5_rb,st2_vs2_bag6_rb,st2_vs2_bag7_rb,st2_vs2_bag8_rb,st2_vs2_bag9_rb"+
        "from cte where rn=1 order by logtime";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's because you're missing a space before from, and end up with this:

```
ORDER BY b.logtime) rnFROM INDUS2_VACUUM
```

Edit: You seem to have a lot of these issues. Maybe you should print out the SQL and check what it actually says.